# Confusion with multichoose: choosing 9 elements from a pool of 2 with repitition. 2 multichoose 9 is 10, but the answer is $2^9$

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we're looking for the number of 9-digit strings made up of only 1s and 0s. For each digit, we have two choices, so the answer is $2^9$.

We can also think of this as choosing $9$ elements (each digit in the string) from a pool of $2$ elements (either $0$ or $1$). But $(2$ multichoose $9)$ is equal to $10$, so this interpretation gives the wrong answer...but why?

Comment: multichoose ignores order? a string or password cannot ignore order

Comment: One of the multichoces is for example "two $0$'s and seven $1$'s", but that comprise $001111111$, $010111111$, $011011111$, and so on

Comment: @user29418 Yep that makes sense now, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "$2$ multichoose $9$" is counting the strings and distinguishing them only by the number of 1's versus the number of $0$'s.

Among the ten outcomes counted by $2$ multichoose $9$ you have "There is one $1$ and the rest are zeroes" and "There are two $1$'s and the rest are zeroes" but it gives no further information about what we counted beyond that.  Every string with exactly one $1$ are treated as "the same."

However, we traditionally consider the string $100000000$ to be different than the string $001000000$ and also different than $000000001$, etc... just like how we consider $111000000$ to be different than $100100100$ and different than $001001100$ etc...

Comment: Ah okay, I was misunderstanding how ordering relates to multichoose. This clarifies things a lot though, thank you!

Comment: @JamesRonald it is worth reminding yourself how each common answer to counting problems relates to a particular phrasing of a problem in terms of balls and bins being distinguishable vs indistinguishable, allowing multiple balls per bin, requiring at least one ball per bin, or allowing exactly one ball per bin, etc...  Multichoose was used as an answer for how many ways you can put indistinguishable balls into distinguishable bins.  $n^k$ was used however for distinguishable balls into distinguishable bins.  See more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Comment: That's really helpful! I never realized we could frame every combinatorics method/technique with such a simple collection of problems. I'm reading that wiki page ASAP, thank you again!

Comment: "*Every*" is a bit strong, there are several problems which don't fall into these categories, and several problems which still haven't been totally solved yet with closed form solutions (*e.g. the [lego problem](http://web.math.ku.dk/~eilers/lego.html)*).  Still, the twelvefold way will cover many elementary counting exercises.